# Stuck in overwrite mode in tmux

Tags: linux, emacs, terminal, tmux

Scenario: I open a new tmux session, and run  **emacs .tmux.conf**.

The second line of .tmux.conf reads: *set-option -g prefix C-a*. I type 'asd', and the second line now reads: *asdset-option -g prefix C-a*. All good.

I ssh to another server, do some stuff, and then close the connection.  I now re-run **emacs .tmux.conf**, and type 'asd'. The second line now reads *asd-option -g prefix C-a*, but if I save and run **emacs .tmux.conf** again, I'll see *asdset-option -g prefix C-a*.

This issue affects all lines except the first, even when I'm typing commands in the prompt.

Sourcing .bashrc, resetting the pane with *respawn-pane*, does not fix this. If I create a new pane or window, the issue is fixed in the new pane or window until I run ssh again.

What's happening? It's clearly a display issue, since inspection of the actual file reveals that i'm not actually overwriting.

Comment: If I ssh to another server, the prompt wraps around - so for instance, if my prompt was:

**username@server2: cd foo/bar/**, and I typed some more, it would become **outputme@server2: cd foo/bar/**. tmux was built locally on server1, if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix the problems of this kind, type in your shell:

```
$ stty sane
```

This is generally an universal one-time fix for terminal left off in a weird state.

To get rid of the problem completely, check your `$TERM` environment variable.

Inside tmux it should be `TERM=screen` (some suffix may present).

tmux does this automatically but your `TERM` environment variable can be altered by shell startup/login scripts.

So, in your tmux window type:

```
$ export TERM=screen
$ emacs <...>
```

If it helps, revise your shell rc files.

Comment: `reset` is another command that, it seems likely, you'd be able to use for fixing this situation.